# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802)

Tags: android, database

I have written some code which is used to delete database folder. It delete database but also throw error. Please suggest me how to solve this problem.

**Code for delete database**

```
public void deleteDB() {
        try {
            File db_path = new File(
                    "/data/data/pacakge_name/databases/mydatabase_db.db");
            db_path.delete();
            System.out
                    .println("Database deleted successfully================================");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("Error==", e.toString());
        }
    }
Cursor cursor = handler.getCategoryData("1");
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("database has data................................");
                        } else {
                            System.out
                                    .println("database has no data.............................");
                            LiveTVCategoryParser category_parser = new LiveTVCategoryParser();
                            category_parser.category_parser(Splash.this, "1",
                                    "live_root");
                        }
```

**Error:**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:838)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:236)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at com.zengamedia.ui.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(  613):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: it is not the db delete that is causing problem , it is the moveToFirst call

Comment: It may be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312563/sqlitediskioexception-disk-i-o-error-code-1802-while-compiling-pragma-jou/45329480#45329480

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should close your Cursors and database *before* deleting the SQLite file.

Comment: Ok, let's start at the beginning. The error probably starts here: `at com.zengamedia.ui.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:51)`. What is what is line 71? Post `run()` in your question.

Comment: Hmm, is `handler` your database handler or adapter?

Comment: Did you make a `close()` method? If not, please post your `open()` method.

Comment: private DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
  DataBase dbobj = new DataBase(context, "database_db.db", null, 1);
  database = dbobj.getWritableDatabase();
 }

 public static DatabaseHandler getinstance(Context context) {
  if (obj == null) {
   obj = new DatabaseHandler(context);
  }
  contextM = context;
  return obj;
 }

Comment: have look i have used Singleton class for this

Comment: Ok, after you have deleted `database_db.db`, how do you expect `handler` to read from the deleted file?

Answer (score 0):

The error code 1802 is [SQLITE_IOERR_FSTAT](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_ioerr_access.html). I'd rather assume something is wrong on the disk level, try to delete the database and check the disk medium.

Answer (score 0):

call this function when database‘s CRUD

```
public synchronized void checkDBIsOpen() {
        try {
            mydb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            NewsLog.error(TAG, "check database is open or not,excetpion:" + Utility2_1.getErrorInfo(e));
        }
    }
```