# SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been having a few crashes that have been coming up more often recently and i cannot figure out how to reproduce them or fix them. Here is the one that comes up most often

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.myapp.MyApplication: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5436)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6154)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:320)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:294)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:680)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:289)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
   at com.myapp.DBConnect.getInstance(DBConnect.java:202)
   at com.myapp.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:66)
```

Every search I try makes it sound like the issue is with trying to open the database from different threads. However, I thought I had a setup to avoid this by having a static method in the helper class to get the current instance.

```
private static DBConnect mInstance = null;
private static SQLiteDatabase db;

public static DBConnect getInstance(Context ctx) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DBConnect(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        db = mInstance.getWritableDatabase(); // this is line 202 in DBConnect.java
        // all methods in this class reference this db var to run database queries
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

and then wherever i need to access the database I have a local variable db set by using this line:

```
// this is line 66 in MyApplication.java
DBConnect db = DBConnect.getInstance(this);
```

then run all my database queries with functions like `db.addItem()`

It has been working fine and I am 90% sure multiple threads are accessing the same tables without me ever seeing crashes. The app has a couple lists which sync in the background in several places, the easiest one to reproduce is when the app first launches it performs a sync of these lists. While it is syncing the user can view the different lists, loading each list is selecting its contents from the database, possibly while items are being added or deleted from the same tables in the background sync process. I also have a couple hundred active users a day and have only seen this kind of crash 15 times over the last few months.

Also, seeing that the first line of the error is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application ...`, It seems like this is happening when the user first launches the app? Not sure how there could already be multiple threads at this point, none of the background processes run unless the user has signed in.

I am also seeing the following error caused by the same line:

```
Failed to change locale for db '/data/user/0/com.myapp/databases/mydb' to 'en_US'.
```

I have tried changing locale settings on my phone, reinstalling the app and then messing around to see if i get this problem. I even tried switching back to English after installing using another locale but have not been able to repeat this crash. I have a feeling they might be related since they both seem to be happening on startup.

Comment: "disk I/O error" means that the flash storage is broken.

Comment: So is there anything I can do about it or should i just ignore it? It just seems weird to me because i had seen this before maybe once a month, but within the last 2-3 months its happened ~15 times between 8 different users. Ive also seen an increase in Out Of Memory errors even though our user volume has remained relatively the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did not give runtime permission. I kept my database file in external storage and when asked for permission I denied it, but when **allowed** permission it was working fine. On SDK version >= 23 you have to give **runtime permission**.

Comment: What is "runtime permission"? Write External Storage permission at runtime?

Comment: @thecr0w for if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) you have to give runtime permission...you can find out more about it from below link
https://www.journaldev.com/10409/android-runtime-permissions-example

Comment: OK, got it. but I kept my db in internal storage, still got the exception. Maybe the internal storage is full, I guess.

Comment: This might be one reason.